# iPod Touch 2nd no response to Run in xcode4.2

Tags: compiler-construction, xcode4.2, ipod-touch, llvm-gcc

Googled for few hours and I got no answers.

There is my steps:

1 create a new project without ARC in xcode4.2
2 add armv6 to a architectures. it shows: armv6 $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)
3 change iOS Deployment Target to iOS4.1
4 check my code signing is Team provisioning

Click Run , it shows build success, but my iPod Touch 2nd (iOS4.2.1) has no response, no error , no warning, nothing in debug output window, no issues...

I think it is the problem with Apple LLVM compiler 3.0, so I change it to LLVM GCC 4.2, then some error pops up, I change the main.m file to this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

And I fix the AppDelegate.h from this:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
```

to

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWindow *window;
```

OK, no warning, no error, no issues, no response ... xcode do not copy files to my Touch 2nd at all!

My old projects created by xcode4.1 and 3.2.5 has no problem with Touch 2nd, all I need to do is add a armv6 support, But xcode 4.2 is really a pain in the 4ss! I think that because it's default compiler is not LVMM GCC 4.2 , so I'm thinking:

1. How to change my xcode4.2's default compiler to LLVM GCC 4.2?
2. If I can't change the default compiler, what should I do to run it on my Touch 2nd?

Any help will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove armv7 as a requirement from your projects plist:(Which seems to be added by default on new Xcode projects)

[image]